# How do I prevent Ionic/React fab button from moving with keyboard?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, floating-action-button

I have a fab button in my App.tsx file. It's overlayed on top of my bottom tab bar, but not actually inside of the tab bar as non tab buttons seem to disappear if I put it inside IonTab.

Currently, when I open the keyboard to type, the fab button moves up with the keyboard. I want it to stay hidden behind the keyboard / not move at all.

I've tried position: absolute, but it still moves up. Here's the current code I have:

```
<IonApp>
    <IonContent>
        <IonPage>
            <IonTab>.....</IonTab>
            <IonFab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="bottom">
                <IonFabButton mode="ios" onClick={() => { scanCode() }}>
                    <IonIcon style={iconStyle} icon={camera}></IonIcon>
                </IonFabButton>
            </IonFab>
        </IonPage>
    </IonContent
</IonApp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `<IonPage>` outside of `<IonContent>`

Like this:

```
<IonApp>
  <IonPage>
    <IonContent>
      ...
    </IonContent>
  </IonPage>
</IonApp>
```